# Run multiple solutions in a single workspace c#

Tags: c#

In c# console applicatiin, is it possible to run multiple solutions so that variables in 1.exe can be controlled from 2.exe

Comment: How communicate the applications? Do you use TCP/IP?

Comment: 1.exe and 2.exe will be on the same computer.

Comment: Search for c# IPC mechanisms

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set up a shared resource for the two applications (1.exe and 2.exe) and read the values from there. It could be a database, cache or even a text file. Refresh the variables from the shared resource when appropriate.

Another solution is that you use TCP/IP (localhost?) and send commands to change the variables. For example: 1.exe is the client and 2.exe is the server. 2.exe sends an updateVariableX command and VariableX will be changed in 1.exe

Comment: I will searh about it and try. Then I'll update the details here :)

Comment: @WayneScicluna another technique is named pipes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ordai, how to use cache please?

Comment: Great article (Velocity Architecture): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx#id0450004 (But I think it is too complex for the purpose of your project).